# Java (SWT/JFace)- handling all exceptions within Runnable

Tags: java, exception, swt, jface

I have an SWT/JFace application that uses the Realm (not sure of the concept) class to run the main program as a thread. I'm trying to catch any uncaught exceptions using a try/catch block around my main code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // ref: http://forums.instantiations.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1583
    Realm.runWithDefault(SWTObservables.getRealm(display), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                window.setBlockOnOpen(true);
                window.open();
                Display.getCurrent().dispose();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                MessageDialog.openError(null, "Error", "Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
                logger.error("Error!!!", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The errors get thrown back to the `window.open()` line fine, but are then passed on to Realm, so the `catch` block is never reached. Here's the end of a stack trace:

```
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at com.ism.MainWindow$1.run(MainWindow.java:210) <-- "window.open();"
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at com.ism.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:204) <-- "Realm.runWithDefault....."
```

Tried putting a try/catch around `Realm.runWithDefault` but that didn't work either.

How do I capture all of the exceptions in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by 'thrown back to the `window.open()` line fine'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some UI runnable is throwing an `Exception` in the display event loop.  You need to set up a different event loop exception handler.  (The default simply prints the exception to the console.)

For example:

```
Window.setExceptionHandler(new Window.IExceptionHandler() {
    public void handleException(Throwable error) {
        MessageDialog.openError(null, "Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Or, of course, you could rethrow and catch at your top-level like in your example.

Note, however, that this is a static method on `Window`, so this exception handler is **application-wide**.

Comment: Still baffled as to why my original try/catch doesn't work, but the example you give works, kudos.

Comment: The default exception handler for the event loop just calls `e.printStackTrace()`.  So nothing actually gets thrown back up to you on the `window.open()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your `catch` block is only catching `Exception`s.  However, you don't say what exceptions are being thrown and not being caught.  So, in the absence of any further information, I'm going to guess that these exceptions are in fact `Error`s.  Try `catch (Throwable e)` instead of `catch (Exception e)`.

Comment: A full stack trace would be handy. So far it seems ai if the NPE thrown was wrapped into an `Error`.